# Table View reload Not updating correctly from Backendless

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, backendless

I am trying to load data from my back endless tables, but I can't get the table to load correctly. It just stays blank.I tried it in multiple places and they would cause a crash. The only place it can go is after the last error call. The table stays blank however.  The relevant code is in my fetchingUserDataAsync() function.

## Here is my table view controller:

```
import UIKit

class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()

 let follow:Follow = Follow()



var usernames = [""]
var userids = [""]
var userEmails = [""]

var isFollowing = [false]


func fetchingUserDataAsync() {

     self.userids.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
     self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.isFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    print("\n============ Fetching user data using the ASYNC API ============")





    let query = BackendlessDataQuery()
    backendless.persistenceService.of(BackendlessUser.ofClass()).find(
        query,
        response: { ( name : BackendlessCollection!) -> () in
            let currentPage = name.getCurrentPage()

            for names in currentPage as! [BackendlessUser] {
                //print("User name = \(names.name)")

                if(names.name != self.backendless.userService.currentUser.name){

                self.usernames.append(names.name)

                    self.backendless.persistenceService.of(BackendlessUser.ofClass()).find(
                        query,
                        response: { ( objectId : BackendlessCollection!) -> () in
                            let currentPage = objectId.getCurrentPage()

                            for objects in currentPage as! [BackendlessUser] {
                                //print("User id = \(objects.objectId)")

                                if(objects.objectId != self.backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId){

                                    self.userids.append(objects.objectId)

                                    let currentUser = self.backendless.userService.currentUser
                                    let user = objects.objectId

                                    let whereClauseOne = "follower = '\(currentUser.objectId)' "

                                    let whereClauseTwo = "following= '\(user)'"

                                    //print ("I am following'\(whereClauseTwo)'")

                                    self.backendless.persistenceService.of(objects.ofClass()).find(
                                        query,
                                        response: { objects -> () in


                                            if let objects = objects{


                                                self.isFollowing.append(true)

                                            } else{

                                                self.isFollowing.append(false)

                                            }



                                        },
                                        error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in
                                            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
                                        }
                                    )


                                }


                            }


                        },
                        error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in
                            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
                        }
                    )


                }


            }



        },
        error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in
            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
        }
    )

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    self.tableView.reloadData()


}





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




    fetchingUserDataAsync()



}
```

Comment: It's best to post only the code relevant to the problem you're asking (you could remove all the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code). And it also helps to format your code nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call reload data after your data arrays are filled with objects , you need to put it inside the response closure and not outside because the response closure is called Async some time later and your reload data as it is now called immediately in your view did load.
Of course when you put it inside you need to dispatch the reload data to the main queue.

Comment: I tried it in the closure, with dispatch_main() and tried dispatch_get_main_queue, but it keeps giving me a index error, or says it can't read the memory.

Comment: finally got it working consistently. I had to put an if statement to make sure that the count was the same for all the arrays and then refresh.